# Hodge numbers of non-commutative varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, mirror-symmetry

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a non-commutative variety, by this I mean  $X$ is a (smooth) algebraic variety and $\mathcal{A}$ is a sheaf of algebra on $X$. One such example in my mind is when $X$ admits a quadric fibration in some vector bundle and $\mathcal{A}$ is the sheaf of the even part of Clifford algebra associated to this fibration as in Kuznestov's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510670) .

Is there a way to define Hodge numbers of $(X, \mathcal{A})$?

I had noticed the paper [Hodge theoretic aspects of mirror symmetry](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510670), however it does not seem to address the above problem. (Honestly speaking, I never finish reading that paper!)

Comment: you can certainly define the Hochschild (co)homology of that category and you might interpret the rank of those vector spaces as sums of whatever the Hodge numbers should be.

Comment: But that is not Hodge numbers rather sum of $p+q = r$ Hodge numbers. I was wondering if there are more direct ways to define Hodge number without going to derived cateogries.